# Deliver failure (Exception) to a promise

Tags: clojure

How can I make the `deref` of this promise throw an Exception, in the same way a future can cause an Exception if the body of the future throws one?

```
(let [p (promise)]
  (something-that-could-deliver-an-error p)
  @p) ; should explode with the delivered Exception
```

I'm currently considering doing this by delivering a `fn` to the promise, but I suspect there's a more idiomatic way to do this.

Background: I'm running multiple futures concurrently. If any of them error, I want to cancel all the other futures immediately and output the error. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: So far I've decided to follow erlang's tagged tuple approach and have things delivered to the promise in the form `[:ok value]` or `[:error exception]`.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure's promises don't have a separate concept of "success" and "failure", rather, they only distinguish whether a promise has been realized. In other words, there's no way to get a Clojure core promise to throw a custom exception when you deference it.

If you're OK with going outside the standard library, you might try using `deferred` objects from Manifold instead:

http://aleph.io/manifold/deferreds.html

A `deferred` object can be fulfilled by either the `success!` or `error!` functions. The former behaves like `deliver`. The latter lets you fulfill the promise with an exception, which is thrown if the deferred is `deref`'d, but can also be "caught" by some of Manifold's other control-flow functions.

```
user=> (require '[manifold.deferred :as d])
nil
user=> (def my-deferred-value (d/deferred))
#'user/my-deferred-value
user=> (d/error! my-deferred-value (ex-info "Error!" {:failed true}))
true
user=> @my-deferred-value
ExceptionInfo Error!  clojure.core/ex-info (core.clj:4617)
```